# Table returning multiple rows for single join match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called "items"

```
    itemNumber | Material
------------------------------
     1234      |  cast
     234A      | Tool Plate
```

And another table called "material"

```
    material    |  Process
--------------------------------
    cast        |  Anodize
    Tool Plate  |  Blah
```

I am doing a select on the tables with a join:

```
Select
Process,Material.Material
from Items
inner join Material on items.Material=material.Material
Where  items.ItemNumber = '1234'
```

and i get a return of

```
anodize   |cast
Tool Plate| cast
```

'cast' has a match of 'Anodize', but its returning each combination. I've tried every join type i know of and it produces the same results. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Your sample data with that query should not return those results.  I am guessing that the data is different from what you expect.  Try setting up a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: That result simply isn't possible to get from that query. Is this the actual query that you are running?

Comment: looks like the table has more values than you show here

Comment: Not related to question: Since you are using both the columns from Material table I'd suggest making that as the primary table in the query and then joining Items table, or using it with sub-query.

Comment: `Select * from items where itemNumber = '1234'` returns just 1 item of 1234 right?  and if you `select * from material where material = 'cast'` what do you get... 2 records?  well then query's working fine and you have more data than you expected for 'cast' in Material table.  If you only get 1 record; then you're not telling us something; or the DB Engine has serious problems.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a typo with `item.Material` (it should be `items.Material`), your query works just fine, assuming that you have presented the facts correctly about your data.

Try out the demo here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49d73f/2)

Answer (score 0):

You query is ok, only had a typo.

Check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbff4/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    items i inner join 
    material m ON i.Material = m.Material
WHERE 
    i.itemNumber = '1234';
```